# Data-binding went stuck after Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6+ (updated 12.21.2018)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, android-developer-api, android-gradle-3.0

I have updated all in Canary 6 of AS 3.1, see [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/12/android-studio-31-canary-6-is-now.html), including data-binding to v2.

Now, something will stuck in wrong, that a lot standard "android:xxxx" cannot be bound, also some customized bind-adapters either.

See here

`Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.TextView.`

`Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onViewAttachedToWindow' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.ScrollView.`

Error in stack:

 `at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:112)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:90)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1033)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1198)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)`

Any tip?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the integration with the kotlin compiler. A bug has been filed on it and it should be fixed in the next canary build.

Comment: Try this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70915745#comment8

Comment: This bug has coated 2 days on me. @George Mount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a critical bug of Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6+ which is committed by 3.1.0-alpha06

issuetracker.google.com/issues/70915745#comment8